# Таблица значений функций с++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, параметры

Всем добрый день.

Задание которое я делал: Сoстaвить прoграмму вывода на экран таблицы значений функции y(x) для x,изменяющегося от a= 0,1 до b=1,2 с шагом h=0,1. Вычисление y(x) оформить в виде функции.Предусмотреть передачу параметров в функцию разными способами.
 [image: задание]

К сожалению я  пока самостоятельно не могу с "нуля" сделать такое(не хватает знаний), поэтому взял пример и переделал под своё задание, скажите пожалуйста правильно ли я переделал или что сделал не так.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
double Summa(double, int);
void Summa(double*, int*, double*);
void Summa(double&, int&, double&);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double s, x, a, b, h; 
    int k;
    cout << "Vvedite a,b,h,k" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> h >> k;// тут ввожу 0.1  1.2 0.1 20
    //Вывод заголовка
    cout << "\n Value" << setw(20) << "Pointer" << setw(24) << "Reference \n";
    x = a;
    do
    { //Вывоод таблицы
        cout << setw(5) << x << setw(10) << Summa(x, k);
        Summa(&x, &k, &s);
        cout << setw(10) << x << setw(10) << s;
        Summa(x, k, s);
        cout << setw(10) << x << setw(10) << s << endl;
        x+=h;
    } while (x <= b+h/2);
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
    double Summa(double x, int k)
    {
    double s;
    const double PI = 3.14159265;
    int i;
    s = 2; 
    for (i = 1; i <=k; i++)
    s += cos(i*PI/4)/pow(i,2)*pow(x,i);
    return s;
    }
    void Summa(double *x, int *k, double *s)
    {
        int i;
        const double PI = 3.14159265;
        *s = 2;
        for (i = 1; i <= *k; i++)
        *s += cos(i*PI / 4) / pow(i, 2)*pow(*x, i);
    }
    void Summa(double &x, int &k, double &s)
    {
        int i;
        const double PI = 3.14159265;
        s = 2;
        for ( i = 1; i <=k; i++)
        s += cos(i*PI / 4) / pow(i, 2)*pow(x, i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, не совсем правильно. Подставьте `x == 0` - что у вас получается? 2. А должно? 0. Вы зачем-то *инициализируете сумму значением 2*.

Так что замените ваше

```
s = 2;
```

на

```
s = 0;
```

и все будет нормально. И еще - я бы не использовал функции - ни `cos`, ни `pow` - они тут не очень-то нужны. Пример, как от них избавиться (и ваш исправленный код) см. тут - https://ideone.com/hZFCct

Comment: В примере сказано, что s=2 т.к. это начальное значение при k=0 . Правда я не совсем понял,как надо. Получается правильно будет 0,как вы говорите?

Comment: Ну вообще-то когда вы начинаете суммировать что-то там - например, долги :), вы же начинаете с нуля? Так и тут - все члены ряда прибавляются к чему?